# SQL to Show Custom Tables Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, types

I created a table type in SQL Server so I could pass a data table into a stored procedure using c#. Is there a SQL Statement I can use to see all the custom table types that were created.

```
CREATE TYPE myTable AS TABLE
(
    intMyTableID int identity(1,1) Not NULL,
    [columnName] varchar(50),
    [valueWas] varchar(50),
    [valueNow] varchar(50)
)
```

In the stored procedure I use it this way:

```
@mytable myTable READONLY
```

There is no way I can see from Object Explorer to see custom created Types so I am asking if there is a SQL Statement I can use to see it.

Comment: *"There is no way I can see from Object Explorer to see custom created Types"* yes there is... They're (unsurprisingly) under Types in the Programmability node.

Comment: As for the T-SQL end, that's `sys.table_types`. The `type_table_object_id` column can be used as the `object_id` for purposes of things like determining the table structure from `sys.columns`.